# Text Grab and Echo?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make it so every week my php code gets text already stored in a pre-made text file and echo's out a new line every week. I have tried using `date()` but it didn't turn out how I expected.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    $text = file_get_contents("lines.txt");  
    $text = trim($text); //This removes blank lines so that your 
    //explode doesn't get any empty values at the start or the end.     
    $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
    $lineNumber = count($array);

    echo "<p>{$array[0]}</p>";
?>
```

Here is how the format for lines.txt looks like :

> 1. Hello1
> 2. Hello2
> 3. Hello3

And On and on

Comment: You need to at least keep a flag somewhere to indicate the week. So my question is how many weeks do you have per testfile? If it has 3 lines like you have written, how can one track the next line for the week without a flag.

Comment: What happened with the `date` usage?

Comment: you can add offset or comment on that line date.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to echo lines from the text file:

```
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
foreach($array as $val){
    echo "$val\n";
}
```

If you want to echo a new line every week, keep track of it somewhere, something like:

```
$counter = 0;
if(!file_exists("date.txt")){
    file_put_contents("date.txt",date("d"));
}else{
    $date = file_get_contents("date.txt");
    $dayNow = date("d");
    $counter = ($dayNow - $date)/7;
}
$text = file_get_contents("lines.txt");  
$text = trim($text);
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
echo $array[$counter]."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution - if I understand your question right:

```
<?php
    $fname  = 'quoteoftheweek.txt';
    if (!file_exists($fname)) {
        $quote  = '???';                       // File does not exist
    } else {
        $lines  = file($fname, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        $nweek  = (integer)date('W',time());  // Get the week number
        $nlines = count($lines);              // Get the number of lines
        // Calculate the index as week_number modulo number_of_lines
        // If number_of_lines < 1 set it to false
        $index  = ($nlines>0) ? ($nweek % $nlines) - 1 : false;
        $quote  = ($index!==false) ? $lines[$index] : '???';
    }

    echo '<p>Quote, week '.$nweek.' : ' . $quote . '</p>';
```

Contents of the *quoteoftheweek.txt* file:

> Quote of the week 1
>   Quote of the week 2
>   Quote of the week 3
>   Quote of the week 4
>   Quote of the week 5
>   Quote of the week 6
> ........

Result (2016-02-15):

> Quote, week 7 : Quote of the week 7

Notes:

- The solution reads the text file right into an array.
  Line-feeds are removed, and empty lines skipped, in one single step.
- It calculates the index into this array as *weeknumber* modulo *numberoflines*. Thus, if there are less lines than weeks, it re-uses lines.
- If the text file should be empty, or does not exist, it displays '???' instead a quote.